# user generated content: how to treat potential copyrighted material?

Tags: copyright

I'm making a game where users can create doodles/images and those can be shared and used in-game (maybe as avatars or part of the interactable elements). I'm not sure how to treat that type of content, since it could be very possible that users might create a Mario-like figure, or Sonic, or Link (from Zelda), etc. Since they would be shared and be part of the game, how should I treat them? Should I ban them? the items in question would be created by the players using tools provided in the app, they would not be able to upload images or anything like that. Is that type of art also under the effect of copyright law?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The person who draws the images owns copyright in them - your terms of service will need to require them to grant you a royalty-free, irrevocable licence. Hire a lawyer.

You will also need policies and procedures to take down material that infringes third party copyright/trademarks. For example, when a user doodles Micky Mouse you need to be able to respond whin Disney complains. hire a lawyer.

Comment: Thanks. That's more or less what i was thinking, and yes, I will definitively hire a lawyer.